# How to use firebase database in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension

I want to use it as part of my content script so that I can fetch data from my firebase database. However, I don't know how I can reference the script that's given in the firebase docs:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

I know that if I was doing it all in the pop up html page, then I could load the script tag, but in the content script, there's no html page other than the content page, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: You'll have to download the script and bundle it with your extension. Or you can allow downloading the SDK in your manifest.json. See https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not using auth though. Just the database so I'm not sure if that link still does the job?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So apparently, I have to upload the extension to the store to actually get it to work? I just did that but is that even necessary?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen followed the instructions but it didn't work.

Comment: @Khalil Hijazi Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @jkupczak Nope, I haven't looked at it in a while. I'll check out the other answer soon hopefully and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ContentScript runs on page's DOM, but on different JS sandbox, so you can't directly inject JS via DOM as it is shown in the example.

I would recommend you to load firebase lib to the background page and then you can access it from your background script and proxy requests from your Content Script via background backend. This will not cause firebase lib loaded every time you load page loads content scripts and it will be load once on background page init (or you can load it by request using non-persistent background script).

Example:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "FireBase Demo",
    "description": "FireBase client demo",    
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ],
     "background": {
       "page": "bg.html",
       "persistent": false
     },
     "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"],
        "js": ["cs.js"]
    }],
     "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**bg.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="bg.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**bg.js**

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  projectId: '...'
});

var db = firebase.firestore();
db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {
    if (msg.command == "add"){
      console.log("process msg add", msg, sender, response);
      db.collection(msg.collection).add(msg.data).then((result) => {
        console.log("success", result)
        response({type: "result", status: "success", data: result, request: msg});
      }).catch((result) => {
        console.log("error", result);
        response({type: "result", status: "error", data: result, request: msg}); 
      });
    }
    return true;
  });
```

**cs.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: "add", collection: "users", data: {name: "user"}}, (msg) => {
  console.log("response", msg)
});
```

Another variant is to load your firebase JS lib and the code you need to run to the page's JS sandbox by injecting it to the page's DOM with something like:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"
document.body.append(script); // firebase lib will be loaded to the page's JS sandbox and page's DOM
var fn = function injectedFunction(seed) { /* your JS code you want to run is page's sandbox */ }
var ele = document.createElement("script");
ele.textContent = fn+"console.log(injectedFunction());";
```

But this variant is very bad, because page's CSP may block your JS in this case.
document.body.appendChild(ele);

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to your extensions manifest file should do the trick:

```
"permissions": [
    "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"
],
```

Once you've done that you should be able to access the API using any normal XHR client from your extensions javascript (be careful for any security concerns).

Comment: Are you suggesting he use that site specifically? What is it?

Comment: @jkupczak No, sorry I forgot I'll change it in a sec.

Comment: @jkupczak Fixed

Comment: @Kenzoid thanks for the suggestion, I'll check it out soon and see if it solves the issue.